# Android need help displaying things from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-layout, adapter

Hello i need Your help in displaying data from database in activity, ive been trying many things but have no idea how to do that. Im creating some kind of weather app. It has Data in Database on the device. 
There is DataBaseHandler Class which returns List with all Spots.

```
public List<Spot> getUserSpotList(int id){
            List<Spot> spotList = new ArrayList<Spot>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT " +SPOT_ID+","+ SPOT_NAME + ","+ SPOT_LATITUDE + ","+SPOT_LONGITUDE+","+SPOT_WIND_SPEED +","+SPOT_WEATHER_ICON+
                    " FROM " + TABLE_SPOT + " WHERE "+SPOT_USER_ID + "="+id;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Spot spot = new Spot();
                    spot.setSpot_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    spot.setSpotName(cursor.getString(1));
                    spot.setSpotLatitude(cursor.getString(2));
                    spot.setSpotLongitude(cursor.getString(3));
                    spot.setWindSpeed(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)));
                    spot.setSpotWeatherIcon(cursor.getString(5));
                    // Adding User to list
                    spotList.add(spot);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        return spotList;
        }
```

And i Have Activity with listView xml in witch i want to display some stuff from the code above based on another relativelayout for one element. 
SpotActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.mk.rcwindy.SpotActivity">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listLajout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**And here is Relative layout for one element in the list view above.
I would like to connect SpotName from database with TextView id=SpotName, Windspeed from database with Windspeed Text View, and Display image in ImageView based on SpotWeatherIcon from database.**
spotlista_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip"
        android:id="@android:id/list">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/SpotAvilabilityIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/green_apple"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/WeatherIcon"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/WindSpeed"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WindSpeed"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/WindSpeedUnit"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="m/s"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/WindSpeedUnit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/SpotAvilabilityIcon"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/WeatherIcon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/WeatherIcon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SpotName"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code of activity SpotActivity

```
public class SpotActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


int loggedUserId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spot);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (null != intent) {
        loggedUserId = intent.getIntExtra("logged", 0);
    }

    String text = "logged user id = "+loggedUserId;
    Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t1.show();




}

public int userIdSender(){
    return loggedUserId;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_spot, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id== R.id.action_new){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SpotAddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("logged",loggedUserId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Thanks for Help! I tried to do that and still have a big problems so now im asking for help. Its a school project im working at and that is the last thing i have to do to make the app work-Display stuff :D

Comment: Where is your list adapter?

Comment: I dont have one, probabily from what i know that is the part where i need help from You. I'm trying to fully understand Adapters but still cant get them to work with my app. @Karakuri

Comment: start with the doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: Is there a chance that someone could help me with that adapter? I can say that its some kinde of dedline situation and for You it probably would be 10 minutes max. Thats not like i was not trying i know that i need adapter just need to understand them :) Otherwise thank You im watching that video right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an adapter for your ListView. I recommend you watch [The World Of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=EBLJVIPKAsfxoATjm4LoAw&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=7rEu-_5ncKefBgZ1Z65y0A).

All an adapter does is provide a view for each item in your data set. For cursor data, you should subclass CursorAdapter and implement the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods at the minimum.